TypeError when I import paseto
When I execute import paseto in Python 3.12.2 I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from repositories.user_repo.routes.user_routes import user_router
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\repositories\user_repo\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from repositories.user_repo.authentication import get_password_hash
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\repositories\user_repo\authentication\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import paseto
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\env\Lib\site-packages\paseto\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from paseto.paseto import (
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\env\Lib\site-packages\paseto\paseto.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pysodium
  File "D:\Pasiphae\cyber-unity-test\env\Lib\site-packages\pysodium\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    sodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('sodium') or ctypes.util.find_library('libsodium'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
    if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

After I traced the error back I noticed that the library directory was not in PATH, so I tried to include it. Unfortunately, PATH was not updated in Python so I tried the following script:
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += (";C:\\Users\\path\\to\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\")

It didn't work either.

The error is the inability to find the 'libsodium' library. Check it's availability.

I tried pip install libsodium and It did not work unfortunately

libsodium can't be installed through pip.
take a look at this, https://doc.libsodium.org/installation or https://py-ipv8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preliminaries/install_libsodium.html
